# How to reference a property from a static member in XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, static

Lets say I have a two classes like this:

```
public class LocalResources
{
    public Color ForegroundColor { get; set; }
}

public static class OrganisationModule
{
    public static LocalResources Resources = new LocalResources 
    { 
        ForegroundColor = Color.FromRgb(32, 32, 32)
    };
}
```

In XAML code, why can't I do this (assuming all the right xml namespaces exist)?

```
<TextBlock Foreground="{x:Static Modules:OrganisationModule.Resources.ForegroundColor}" />
```

When I compile, I get the error: `Cannot find the type 'OrganisationModule.ColorManager'. Note that type names are case sensitive.`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two mistakes here. First in the  OrganisationModule class you need to provide Resources as property. Currently it is not a property, you need to write Get and/or Set

Then for Binding we need below expression

```
Foreground="{Binding Path=ForegroundColor,Source={x:Static Modules:OrganisationModule.Resources}}" />
```

Comment: Ahh, of course! Actually, I didn't need to make Resource a property, since it's static, but otherwise this was definitely the answer I needed. Thanks!